# Spring boot 2.0/Tomcat 8.5 - Session attribute in log file

Tags: session, tomcat, redis

I want to log the username from which every request was made.
After successfully logged in, I use this method to set the username to session variable - username.

```
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = merchandiserRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName()).getUsername();
        request.getSession(true).setAttribute("username", username);
        logger.warn("Successfully logged in: " + username);
        response.sendRedirect("/page/1");
    }
```

And in my Tomcat log pattern is:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %{username}s %t "%r" %s %b %T %{User-Agent}i
```

Where %{username}s should be the username, but it displays " - "
I saw this attribute from - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html

I'm using redis for session persistent. 
Any suggestions why it is not working?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the session variable.  If you are logging in and have a spring security context, your @AuthenticatedPrincipal should have the UserDetails/Principal.  Does your logger print the username to the logs correctly in your example?

Comment: The logger has worked correctly. The problem is that the username is not available in Tomcat log file.. :)

Comment: Are you seeing " - - " in the log file?  If you are setting the %{username}s I don't think it defaults to - if its missing.  Can you show me an example of the log output?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  I accomplished the same thing, a slightly different way.

Try adding this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.rakugakibox.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my logback-access.xml which I put into my src/main/resources/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <configuration debug="false" scan="false">
        <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener"/>
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder">
                <fieldNames>
                    <message>message</message>
                </fieldNames>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </configuration>
```

I don't know the root cause of your issue, but this might be a solution to what you are trying to accomplish.